# processdialog don't show on app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want load info invoice from server to client.but during loading, process dialog not be shown, so I do not know the load when it will be completed. Can you help me? Or is there a way to display dialog in the load process, please guide me!

Code callUrl

```
public class CallUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

public static final int POST_TASK = 1;
public static final int GET_TASK = 2;         
private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";
// thời gian chờ của một kết nối, tính theo milliseconds (waiting to connect)
private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000; 
// thời gian chờ của một socket, tính bằng milliseconds (waiting for data)
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;   
private int taskType = GET_TASK;
private Context mContext = null;
private String processMessage = "Processing...";
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

//Khởi tạo
public CallUrl(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

    this.taskType = taskType;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.processMessage = processMessage;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pDlg.dismiss();
}

//thêm thông tin cần thiết để gửi lên server 
public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

//Hiển thị dialog trong quá trình load data
private void showProgressDialog() {

    pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
    pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
    pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pDlg.setCancelable(false);
    pDlg.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    showProgressDialog();
}

//kết nối đến server thông url
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String url = urls[0];
    String result = "";
    HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);
    if (response == null) {
        return result;
    } else {
        try {

            result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// khởi tạo socket và kết nối
private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

    HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();   
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT); 
    return htpp;
}

//thao tác xử lý khi kết nối đến server 
private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        switch (taskType) {

        case POST_TASK:
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            // Add parameters
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            break;
        case GET_TASK:
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

    }

    return response;
}

//Chuyển thông tin nhận về thành dạng chuỗi
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        // đọc thông tin nhận được cho đến khi kết thúc
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }

    // Trả về giá trị chuỗi đầy đủ
    return total.toString();
}

}
```

Code main

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invoice);
    doTimerTask();

    }
  public void doTimerTask() {
    TimerTask mTimerTask;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    testNetwork();
                    Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
                }
            });
        }
    };
    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
    t.schedule(mTimerTask, 500, 300000); //
}
  public void testNetwork()
{
    // Kiểm tra kết nối đến server
    TestConnectionNew test = new TestConnectionNew();
    try {
        String recieve = test.execute("http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php").get();
        if (recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("true") && isNetworkAvailable() == true)
        {
            loaddata();
        }
        else if (recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("false") || isNetworkAvailable() == false)
        {
            String mess = "Không thể kết nối đến server hoặc thiết bị chưa có kết nối mạng!";
            Toast.makeText(Invoice.this, mess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  public void workoffline()
{
    clearArray();
    try {
        mDb.openDB();
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.getAllInvoice(IDDelivery);
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                codeInvoiceArray.add(mCursor.getString(1));
                nameArray.add(mCursor.getString(2));
                phonenumberArray.add(mCursor.getString(3));
                addressArray.add(mCursor.getString(4));
                urlArray.add(mCursor.getString(5));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            loaddatalistview();
        }
        mDb.closeDB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// lấy dữ liệu từ server về thiết bị
public void loaddata()
{
    String phonenumber, name, address, url, code;
    JSONArray jArray;
    try
    {
        clearArray();
        String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/monthlytarget.php";
        CallUrl wst = new CallUrl(CallUrl.GET_TASK, this, "Lấy thông tin hóa đơn...");
        String result = wst.execute(new String[] {
                sampleURL
        }).get();

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            notification("Hôm nay không còn gì để giao!");
        }
        else
        {
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Orders");
            // Mở kết nối đến database
            mDb.openDB();

            // sử dụng json lấy các giá trị thông qua các key
            // gán nó vào các mảng tương ứng
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Lây thông tin theo mã id của người giao hàng
                if (json_data.getString("DeliveryId").equalsIgnoreCase(IDDelivery))
                {
                    phonenumber = json_data.getString("PhoneNumber");
                    address = json_data.getString("Address");
                    name = json_data.getString("CustomerName");
                    url = json_data.getString("Url");
                    code = json_data.getString("CodeInvoice");
                    save(code, url);
                    // Kiểm tra mã hóa đơn này đã có trong database chưa
                    // nếu chưa sẽ thêm data vào databse
                    // nếu đã có rồi sẽ cập nhật lại thông tin thông qua mã
                    // hóa đơn
                    if (mDb.test(code) == true)
                    {
                        mDb.insert(code, name, phonenumber, address, url, "PACKED",
                                IDDelivery);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mDb.editAll(code, name, phonenumber, address, url, IDDelivery, "PACKED");

                    }
                }
            }
            // Thực hiện xong, đóng kết nối
            mDb.closeDB();
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Hiển thị thông tin nhận được lên listview
    workoffline();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here :

```
String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/monthlytarget.php";
CallUrl wst = new CallUrl(CallUrl.GET_TASK, this, "Lấy thông tin hóa đơn...");
String result = wst.execute(new String[] {
        sampleURL
}).get();    //<<<<<<<<<<you are using execute().get()
```

you are using [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) for getting data from `CallUrl` AsyncTask because `get()` method block execution of UI Thread until  result not retrieves   from `AsyncTask` as doc says :

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

so to avoid blocking of UI Thread and show alertbox you will need to execute `CallUrl` as :

```
String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/monthlytarget.php";
CallUrl wst = new CallUrl(CallUrl.GET_TASK, Invoice.this, 
                                          "Lấy thông tin hóa đơn...");
wst.execute(new String[] {
        sampleURL
});
```

and use `onPostExecute` for updating UI when `doInBackground` execution complete

Comment: if you do not use get(), how do I get the return value of class CallUrl.

Comment: no need to return just move your code inside onPostExecute because this method called when CallUrl execution complete and you will get final result in "result" parameter of onPostExecute(String result)

Comment: but when i use " String result = wst.execute(new String[] {
                    sampleURL
            });" and recieve notice "can't convert Asynctask to String ".

Comment: @user1820815 : use `wst.execute(new String[] { sampleURL });` instead of `String result = wst.execute(new String[] { sampleURL });`

Comment: if handled onPostExecute, class callurl only be used once.How can I use this class in many other functions.can you help me?

Comment: @user1820815 : i'm not getting you can you explain it what you want?

Comment: suppose I have a class A and B together call to class CallUrl and receiving information returned is a string of information (If i use the get()).If I handle in "onPostExecute".only class A is the value returned from the server.Class B does not.You can help me fix the function "onPostExecute" so that it can serve for both class A and B

Comment: @user1820815 : create code for both class's in onPostExecute and use if-else for executing according to class from which CallUrl  executed use can send an extra param in CallUrl contractor for identify from which CallUrl is executing in onPostExecute

Comment: so in my handle in the class related to the UI activity, so if into "onPostExecute" will be difficult.

Comment: @user1820815 : not difficult just pass Current Activity Context to CallUrl by which you can access all UI elements inside onPostExecute. if you do code in this way then your code is more readable or in manage way

Comment: suppose, I want to manipulate the code "Intent j = new Intent (Login.this, Invoice.class);
                j.putExtra ("ID", txtusername.getText (). toString ());
                startActivity (j);
                checkBox.setChecked (false); " function onPostExecute. it will error message : "not find activity Login checkbox and composition". should I do?

Comment: @user1820815 : use `Intent j = new Intent (mContext, Invoice.class); j.putExtra ("ID", txtusername.getText (). toString ()); mContext.startActivity (j); checkBox.setChecked (false);` for starting Activity from onPostExecute

Comment: I did like you, but it still can not found txtusername and CheckBox!

Comment: @user1820815 : have you tried as `mContext.txtusername.getText().toString()` ?

Comment: I did try and get the message: "txtusername cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: @user1820815 : there are lots of way to send textview values to CallUrl by using constructor also

Comment: @user1820815 :try this way also  `TextView txt=(TextView)mContext.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview); String strtextvalue=txt.getText().toString()`

Comment: doing so, I can only send the value of the TextView.suppose, if I log in with the password is incorrect, it will set the TextView on drums, Class CallUrl will not do.

Comment: @user1820815 : ok try my last comment

Comment: thank you, I do.But I have a problem, let's say I have 2 processes running "loaddata ();
                workoffline (); ". When loaddata process finished, the result will be be transferred to inside workoffline to show on the listview. But when loaddata not finished, it has passing should workoffline and my listview still empty data, don't data is displayed. I see on google, can be use "android synchronized", but I do not know what to do. you can help me.

Comment: @user1820815 : ok sure i will try to help you .just make new question for next issue and mark this answer as answer if it really help you in solving issue as u have  in this question.thanks so much friend !!!:)